# d3 render wrong coordinates (with offset)

Tags: d3.js

i try to create graph with date on x axis but points render with some offset

offset is depends on the tick marks on the axes X

[image: Bias]

```
        this.mappedData = window._.map(this.data, (item, key) => {
            return {
                date: new Date(key),
                ...item
            };
        });
        var minDate = window._.min(dates);
        var maxDate = window._.max(dates);

        this.xScale = d3.scaleTime()
            .domain([minDate, maxDate])
            .range([0, this.width]);

        var yRange = window._.transform(this.mappedData, function(result, n) {
            result.push(n.dau);
            result.push(n.nau);
        }, []);

        var minRange = window._.min(yRange);
        var maxRange = window._.max(yRange);
        this.yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([minRange, maxRange])
            .range([this.height, 0]);
        var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

        var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((minDate.getTime() - maxDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
        this.axisX = d3.axisBottom(this.xScale)
            .ticks(diffDays)
            .tickFormat(this.formatDate);

        this.axisY = d3.axisLeft(this.yScale);


    this.svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "dau")
        .attr("d", this.lineNau(this.mappedData));
```

[Issue Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9o89193a/6/)

Anyone know why that happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add parseDate:

   `this.parseDate = d3.timeParse('%Y-%m-%d');`
2. prepare data:

   `this.mappedData = window._.map(this.data, (item, key) => {
           return {
               date: self.parseDate(self.formatDate(new Date(key))),
               ...item
           };
      });`
3. call nice function:

   `this.xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([minDate, maxDate]).nice(d3.timeDay) // or without arguments
        .range([0, this.width]);`

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9o89193a/12/)